# How to subtract two sub-arrays from 2D array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have a 2d-array of coordinate points:

```
array = [
  [24, 2],  # => A
  [32, 42], # => B
  [3, 11],  # => C
  [5, 9],   # => D
  [10, 5],  # => E
  [14, 2]   # => F
]
```

I need to find out the distance between each, such as from A to B, C, D, ..., from B to C, D, E, ...

I don't know how to build a loop that goes through all the elements and and how to integrate the distance formula.

Comment: Do you have an expected output format, or anything will do? Also, do you have a function with the distance formula? If so, can you include it in the question?

Comment: Using the Vector class (`require 'matrix'`), you can do something like `array.map { |e| Vector.elements(e) }.combination(2).map { |point| (point.first - point.last).magnitude }`. But this is just a suggestion, since it's not clear what's the desired output format.

Comment: @iGian, I just noticed your comment after earlier posting an answer that implements your suggestion.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, I see you expanded it pretty well.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
require 'matrix'

def pair_wise_distances(h)
  h.map { |k,v| [k, Vector[*v]] }.
    combination(2).
    each_with_object({}) { |((k1,v1),(k2,v2)),g|
      g[[k1,k2]] = (v2-v1).magnitude.round(4) }.
    tap { |g| g.default_proc = Proc.new { |f,k| f[k.reverse] } }
end
```

**Example**

```
h = { A: [24,2], B: [32,42], C: [3,11], D: [5,9], E: [10,5], F: [14,2] }

g = pair_wise_distances(h)
  #=> {[:A, :B]=>40.7922, [:A, :C]=>22.8473, [:A, :D]=>20.2485,
  #    [:A, :E]=>14.3178, [:A, :F]=>10.0,    [:B, :C]=>42.45,
  #    [:B, :D]=>42.638,  [:B, :E]=>43.0465, [:B, :F]=>43.8634,
  #    [:C, :D]=>2.8284,  [:C, :E]=>9.2195,  [:C, :F]=>14.2127,
  #    [:D, :E]=>6.4031,  [:D, :F]=>11.4018, [:E, :F]=>5.0}
g[[:A, :B]]
  #=> 40.7922
g[[:B, :A]]
  #=> 40.7922
```

**Explanation**

See [Vector::[]](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Vector.html#method-c-5B-5D), [Vector#-](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Vector.html#method-i-2D), [Vector#magnitude](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Vector.html#method-i-magnitude) (a.k.a. `r`) and [Array#combination](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Array.html#method-i-combination).

Notice that the method does not require the values in the hash to be two-element arrays. They can be of arrays of any size.

The steps are as follows.

```
f = h.map { |k,v| [k, Vector[*v]] }
  #=> [
  #     [:A, Vector[24, 2]], [:B, Vector[32, 42]], [:C, Vector[3, 11]],
  #     [:D, Vector[5, 9]], [:E, Vector[10, 5]], [:F, Vector[14, 2]]      
  #   ]
e = f.combination(2)
  #=> #<Enumerator: [
  #     [:A, Vector[24, 2]], [:B, Vector[32, 42]], [:C, Vector[3, 11]],
  #     [:D, Vector[5, 9]], [:E, Vector[10, 5]], [:F, Vector[14, 2]]
  #   ]:combination(2)>
```

We can convert `e` to an array to see the (`e.size = 5*4/2 = 15`) values that will be generated by the enumerator.

```
e.to_a
  #=> [
  #     [[:A, Vector[24, 2]], [:B, Vector[32, 42]]],
  #     [[:A, Vector[24, 2]], [:C, Vector[3, 11]]],
  #     ...
  #     [[:A, Vector[24, 2]], [:F, Vector[14, 2]]],
  #     [[:B, Vector[32, 42]], [:C, Vector[3, 11]]],
  #     ...
  #     [[:C, Vector[3, 11]], [:D, Vector[5, 9]]],
  #     ...
  #     [[:D, Vector[5, 9]], [:E, Vector[10, 5]]],
  #     ...
  #     [[:E, Vector[10, 5]], [:F, Vector[14, 2]]]
  #   ]
```

Continuing,

```
f = e.each_with_object({}) { |((k1,v1), (k2,v2)),g|
  g[[k1,k2]] = (v2-v1).magnitude.round(4) }
  #=> (as shown in "Example" section)
```

The value of `[:A, :B]` (the distance between `:A` and `:B`), for example, is computed as follows.

```
diff = Vector[32, 42] - Vector[24, 2]
  #=> Vector[8, 40]

diff.magnitude.round(4)
  #=> 40.7922
```

which, as one would expect, equals

```
Math.sqrt(8**2 + 40**2).round(4)
```

Lastly, for each key `k` in the hash `f`, we need to have `f[k.reverse]` return `f[k]`. (For the key `[:A, :B]`, for example, need to return the value of `[:B, :A]`, which is the same as the value of `[:A, :B]`). We could add the "reverse" keys:

```
g.keys.each { |k| g[k.reverse] = g[k] }
```

but this doubles the size of the hash. Instead, I have attached a default proc to `f`:

```
f.default_proc = Proc.new { |g,k| g[k.reverse] }
```

This causes `f[k.reverse]` to be returned when `f` does not have a key `k`:

```
g[[:A, :B]]
  #=> 40.7922
g[[:B, :A]]
  #=> 40.7922
```

If we wish `f[[k, k]]` (e.g., `f[[:C, :C]]`) to return zero, we could change the default proc to the following.

```
f.default_proc = Proc.new { |g,k| k.first==k.last ? 0 : g[k.reverse] }
f[[:C, :C]]
  #=> 0
f[[:B, :A]]
  #=> 40.7922
```

Comment: Note that @iGain suggested this approach in a comment on the question.

Answer (score 1):

One other option to find the distance between points is to create a patch to array Class, then implement as already shown by Cary Swoveland.

This is the module, `distance_from` is just the Pitagora formula.

```
module ArrayAlgebraPatch
  def distance_from(other)
    # raise "SIZE ERROR" if self.size != other.size
    Math.sqrt(self.zip(other).map { |e| (e[1]-e[0])**2 }.reduce(&:+))
  end
end
```

Yu must include the module to Array class:

```
Array.include ArrayAlgebraPatch
```

So you are able to call:

```
[24,2].distance_from [32,42] #=> 40.792156108742276
```

And apply to your vector, finding distance between points in combination:

```
array.combination(2).map { |pt1, pt2| pt2.distance_from pt1 }
```

Anyway, if a standard lib (such as `Vector`) already does what we need, **we better not reinvent the wheel**.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your array to a hash as it made more sense.

```
class DistanceCalculator
  def initialize(x, y)
    @point_x = x
    @point_y = y
  end

  def coord_difference
    @coord_difference ||= @point_x.zip(@point_y).map { |x, y| y - x }
  end

  def distance
    Math.sqrt(coord_difference.first ** 2 + coord_difference.last ** 2)
  end
end

points = {
  A: [24,2],
  B: [32,42],
  C: [3,11],
  D: [5,9],
  E: [10,5],
  F: [14,2]
}

# example usage
puts DistanceCalculator.new(points[:A], points[:B]).distance
```